# get the summary of an article with the_excerpt function in a wordpress site

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In my WP site I have some articles like this:

```
<a href="http://www.liberta.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/IMG_0143.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-247308" src="http://www.liberta.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/IMG_0143.jpg" alt="IMG_0143" width="1632" height="1224" /></a>

<strong>Il livello del Po a Piacenza</strong> è cresciuto di due metri in una giornata. Il Grande Fiume è osservato speciale in seguito alle abbondanti piogge che hanno colpito il Piemonte provocando la piena degli affluenti. Per tutta la giornata di oggi sono previste piogge in attenuazione dalla serata.
“L’innalzamento del fiume è molto rapido – spiega Massimo Valente di Aipo – al momento il Po a Piacenza è arrivato a 3.30 e l’ondata di piena è attesa già domani ma sarà più intensa nelle giornata di sabato. Aipo sta monitorando costantemente la situazione”.

<a href="http://www.liberta.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/IMG_0144.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-247310" src="http://www.liberta.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/IMG_0144.jpg" alt="IMG_0144" width="1632" height="1224" /></a>
```

In the single.php page I've to extrapolate the summary of the article (the first phrase). The code is the following:

```
<div class="summary-content"><h3 class="sommario"><?php ... ?></h3></div>
```

I think that I use the_excerpt() function but I don't know the way to use it.
What is the php code to insert into  to extrapolate the following text from the article:

```
Il livello del Po a Piacenza è cresciuto di due metri in una giornata. Il Grande Fiume è osservato speciale in seguito alle abbondanti piogge che hanno colpito il Piemonte provocando la piena degli affluenti
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Wordpress website as a reference. Everything [you could possibly want to know](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/#user-contributed-notes) is available there if you take a little time to look.